# Error trying to install Acumos Clio using AIO

Tags: acumos

Background： Openstack VM(rocky) ubuntu16.04-64bit 16G RAM + 8Core CPU + 100GB disk

Done the following steps:

- git clone -b 3.0.1 https://gerrit.acumos.org/r/system-integration (both in ubuntu and root)
- bash system-integration/tools setup_docker.sh (in /home/ubuntu)
- if [[ "$(id -nG "$USER"| grep docker)" == "" ]];then sudo usermod -aG docker $USER; fi
- bash system-integration/tools/setup_k8s_stack.sh setup (in /home/ubuntu)
- cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf /root/ (as root user)
- export KUBECONFIG=/root/admin.conf (as root user)
- bash system-integration/AIO/setup_prereqs.sh k8s acumos $USER generic 2>&1
  | tee aio_prep.log (as root user in /home/ubuntu)
- bash oneclick_deploy.sh 2>&1 | tee aio_deploy.log (as root user in /home/ubuntu)

Failed at last step **Error: YAML parse error on lum-helm/templates/deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 36: mapping values are not allowed in this context.**

Answer (score 1):

I got to know where exactly the error was in my deployment.yaml file it is as follows:

containers:

```
    - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}

      image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.imagetag }}

      imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
```

But in my values file imagetag is commented, I uncommented and it worked.

Comment: when I change the values.yaml it gets overridden every time I re run the installation.

Comment: @sandejai yeah even i faced the same issue, so i tried these 3 steps and redeployed my pod(after uncommenting imagetag in values file):   
`helm dependency build ${pathToLumHelmChart}`
`helm install -f kubernetes/values.yaml --name $LUM_RELEASE_NAME  --namespace ${LUM_NAMESPACE} --debug  ${pathToLumHelmChart}`
`kubectl apply -f kubernetes/external-name.yaml`